# SoapUI TestCase - How to extract raw response(JSON) string Request for the second step

Tags: json, rest, soapui, soap-client

I am using SOAP-UI freeware, I got below **Raw response** from RestAPI Call :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Token: 30d80b5c-ef73-4549-bac1-86480d20da01
TokenExpiry: 899.984446
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Token,TokenExpiry
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 08 Nov 2016 00:27:14 GMT
Content-Length: 12

"Authorized"
```

I need to use property value of ***Token*** variable into another API call as header.

please view attached image to clear any doubt -
[click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x63nB.png)***

It would be great if you could guide how can i write script or any other method to transfer property to another API call

Thanks in advance

[SOAPUI step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0nlk.png)

Comment: You have asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414465/how-to-get-header-data-from-a-raw-json-response-and-pass-to-another-request-usin/40416734#40416734) and you seemed to not look at the answer provided there despite explicitly requested you. What are you expecting by duplicating the question? Please be aware of other people time as well. Feel free to provide your feed back for the answer provide on the earlier question and happy to help.

Comment: Are  you the same user and is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40414465/how-to-get-header-data-from-a-raw-json-response-and-pass-to-another-request-usin/40416734#40416734) yours?

Comment: @Rao This is exactly the question I wanted to ask but the duplicate answer you are reffering to is no longer there so now I don't know where to look for an answer.